# Updating between 2 times(MS Access sql)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to make query which will update salary of emloyee when he will be on night shift. Night shift start at 21:00:00 but they could come earlier or late so i gave them more time.After trying to run this query it came up updating some of times but i didnt find any connection betweeen them. Is it possible to convert it to time or make it work somehow ?
Im working in MS access SQL

```
UPDATE Table SET Table.Salary= (Table.Salary*1.5)
WHERE Table.StartShift between Format("20:00:00","hh:mm:ss") AND Format("23:00:00","hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Table.Salary = (Table.Salary*1.5)
WHERE Table.StartShift Between #20:00:00# And #23:00:00#;
```